# iText 7 PdfTextFormField setValue not working for some characters

Tags: itext7

The `setValue` method for the `com.itextpdf.forms.fields.PdfFormField` class described [here](https://api.itextpdf.com/iText7/java/7.1.6/com/itextpdf/forms/fields/PdfFormField.html#setValue-java.lang.String-) does not seem to work with some characters.

When I try to enter the string `ßěščřžýáíé♠♥︎♦♣Ś` manually in Acrobat Reader or Acrobat Pro, it looks greats; however, when I do it using the `setValue` method, the value does get set correctly, but the display value looks like `ßěščřžýáíé` (the last 5 characters are gone). The font I use is Helvetica, which definitely supports these characters, so I am puzzed as to what's going on.

I've uploaded a sample file I'm using [here](https://easyupload.io/n3nyed). The "Last Name" was entered in Acrobat Pro, so it shows up fine, and I'm trying to enter the "First Name".

Comment: *"The font I use is Helvetica, which definitely supports these characters, so I am puzzed as to what's going on."* - Helvetica with which encoding?

Comment: @mkl I am not sure. How do I find out?

Comment: By inspecting the PDF using RUPS or something similar. Or by sharing the PDF, so that we can inspect.

Comment: @mkl I've uploaded the file I am using as a test and updated my question.

Answer (score 1):

Text field appearances are to be generated using the information in the **DA** (default appearance) entry of the field.

The `first_name` field in your PDF in its **DA** entry refers to a font with an embedded Arial font program and an **Encoding** value of **MacRomanEncoding** with minor adaptions. In particular this encoding does not include the characters "♠♥︎♦♣Ś".

When you set the field value to "ßěščřžýáíé♠♥︎♦♣Ś", iText uses the **DA** information to select the font and tries to encode that value for that font. As the last five characters of the value cannot be encoded, they are dropped.

On the other hand, when Adobe Acrobat filled in the `last_name` field, it created an additional font with glyphs for the five missing characters. Then it generated the field appearance using glyphs both from the originally embedded font referenced from the **DA** entry and from the newly generated font.

So in essence the creator of the form fields in your PDF (by design or by mistake) did not design the form for use with those five problem characters. Adobe Acrobat overrules this limitation by adding the missing glyphs. iText goes by the spec and can not display those five characters.

The behavior of iText here is according to the PDF specification while the behavior of Adobe Acrobat strictly speaking is violating it.

Users often prefer a behavior like that of Adobe Acrobat, though. Consequentially there is a way in iText to also ignore limitations set up by the form creator: The `PdfFormField` class has an additional `setValue` overload that allows you to make iText generate an appearance using a font you provide and, therefore, can in its encoding contain all the needed characters:

```java
/**
 * Set text field value with given font and size
 *
 * @param value    text value
 * @param font     a {@link PdfFont}
 * @param fontSize the size of the font
 * @return the edited field
 */
public PdfFormField setValue(String value, PdfFont font, float fontSize)
```

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed response. Could you tell me how you determined that the field encoding is "MacRomanEncoding"? Also, based on your answer, instead of solving this problem in code, I could also solve this problem by changing the PDF form field encoding. Any idea how to do that?

Comment: @Vadim *"Could you tell me how you determined that the field encoding is "MacRomanEncoding"?"* - I inspected your file using iText RUPS.

Comment: *"Also, based on your answer, instead of solving this problem in code, I could also solve this problem by changing the PDF form field encoding. Any idea how to do that?"* - Unfortunately I don't know which tools allow you to do that. I only receive forms, I don't create them.